# SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, microsoft-edge

I am using microsoft edge driver for the automation and driver is not responding. This is the error message I am not getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. 
Host info: host: 'YOGESH', ip: '192.168.1.7'
Build info: version: '4.10.0', revision: 'c14d967899'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.7
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDrivertext
```

Console error image:

[image: console error image]

Comment: i tried using chromedriver but there is an issue with new chromedriver so i decided to go with edge driver but its also not working

Answer (score 2):

Just like the way you passed the full path of the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) executable along with the extension as:

```
C:\\Users\\yoges\\Downloads\\chromedriver-win32 (1)\\chromedriver-win32.exe
```

Similarly, you also have to pass the full path of the [EdgeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) executable along with the extension as follows:

```
C:\\Users\\yoges\\Downloads\\edgedriver_win64\\edgedriver.exe
```